# Using mRMRe for feature selection with Categorical target variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, bioinformatics, feature-selection, categorical-data

I am trying to use the `mRMRe` package in R to do a feature selection on a gene expression dataset.

My target variable is a categorical variable, i.e. each sample is associated to a class, which is used as target variable.

However, by using the `mRMRe` package, I get the following error when I try to load the data:

```
data <- mRMR.data(data = data)

Error in .local(.Object, ...): data columns must be either of numeric, ordered factor or Surv type
Traceback:

1. mRMR.data(data = data)
2. new("mRMRe.Data", ...)
3. initialize(value, ...)
4. initialize(value, ...)
5. .local(.Object, ...)
6. stop("data columns must be either of numeric, ordered factor or Surv type")
```

The first column has categorical labels, e.g. "Class1", "Class2", etc. When I use `str(data)` I get that the first column is of `Factor` type. However, it cannot be ordered because it is categorical.

Could it be possible that `mRMRe` cannot handle categorical data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received an answer from the developers and:

> The target variable can be categorical only if ordered. In the case of 2 categories, the order is arbitrary. For more categories that are not logically ordered (multicategorical classification) mRMRe is not adapted.

So in this case I cannot use it since my labels are categorical.

Answer (score 1):

The column has to be converted into ordered factor by `ordered(data$variable1)` `str(data)` should look like `Ord.factor`